# Setting object property and checking in Start() if it's null not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the problem is when instantiating a prefab with a script `UnitScript`. When instantiating the prefab, I want to set a variable manually:

```
GameObject unit = newUnit(this.transform.position); // Returns a prefab in the given position
unit.GetComponent<UnitScript>().myProperty = new MyObject(unit.GetComponent<UnitScript>());
print("myProperty was set");
```

The problem appears in the `Start()` method on this `UnitScript`, where `myProperty` appears as `null` instead the value I gave before:

```
void Start() {
    if (myProperty == null) {
        print("myProperty is null");
    }
}
```

Note that the console logs in this order:
myProperty was set, myProperty is null

The `newUnit` method:

```
return Instantiate(myPrefab, position, rotation) as GameObject;
// myPrefab is a public GameObject var that has a prefab given by the inspector
```

The MyObject class looks like this:

```
public class MyObject: Object {

    private UnitScript unit;

    public MyObject(UnitScript unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, I bet the issue is a stupid one...

Comment: Are you sure your `unit.GetComponent<UnitScript>()` returns the same instance as the `UnitScript` instance that prints out "myProperty is null"? Do you instantiate the game object with `Instantiate()`?

Comment: Could you show your newUnit method? :)

Comment: @LibertyLocked yes

Comment: @JoRouss see my edit, I have added the line with the `Instantiate` method. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> return Instantiate(gameObject, position, rotation) as GameObject;
>   // gameObject is a public GameObject var that has a prefab given by the inspector

Try changing the name of your "gameObject" variable since it already exists. gameObject is refering to the GameObject on which your script is attached to.

```
public GameObject PREFAB_GO;
```

Don't forget to reassign it in the inspector.

So it will look like this:

```
return Instantiate(PREFAB_GO, position, rotation) as GameObject;
```

**EDIT**

Try to see if you MyObject() is null.

```
GameObject unit = newUnit(this.transform.position); // Returns a prefab in the given position
    var test = new MyObject();
    if (test == null)
    {
        print("test IS NULL");
    }
    unit.GetComponent<UnitScript>().myProperty = test;
    print("myProperty was set");
```

**ANSWER**

> Found the problem / solution: MyObject class was subclass UnityEngine.Object, for some reason initialising with new doesn't work. Changed to System.Object, and everything is OK.

This is the answer provided by the author in the comments

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The thing is that I have methods between that has this gameObject as a variable, but the actual public class property is not called gameObject, so this shouldn't be the issue. Updated the example for better understanding.

Comment: You are right: MyObject is null! I added the constructor in the OP... I wasn't even considering this, because I use the same constructor somewhere else and it is working....

Comment: Found the problem / solution: `MyObject` class was subclass `UnityEngine.Object`, for some reason initialising with `new` doesn't work. Changed to `System.Object`, and everything is OK. Update your answer and I'll mark it as the correct one :) Thanks!

Comment: Good! Glad I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If MyObject class inherit from MonoBehaviour it's a basic behavior.

In fact you can't call any constructor of a class than inherit of MonoBehaviour. And if you do, Constructor will return null. That's why you can have a null attribute.

If MyObject have to inherit from MonoBehaviour create an Init method that initialize the class. In your case you can use AddComponent method that attached a new instance of your script. Don't forget to move everything from your constructor to a start or an awake method.

You should have : 
unit.GetComponent().myProperty = gameObject.AddComponent();

We need to see MyObject class to help you more.

Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Thanks, but `MyObject` inherits from `Object`. The problem was between UnityEngine.Object and System.Object, creating a new UnityEngine.Object using `new` returns `null`.

Comment: Ok!! It's easy : write System.Object instead of Object